# MySQL: JOIN query that gets all items with a nullable field

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, null

I have an `item` table, which has a foreign key reference to a `tax` table. The column is `tax_id`.

I used to have the `tax_id` as `NOT NULL` in my schema, however I just changed this because I want it to be optional, so now it is `NULL DEFAULT NULL` in the schema.

This has broken my query. Now when I query for items and join the taxes, I only get the ones where the `tax_id` field matches.

This is my query:

```
SELECT item.*
FROM item
JOIN user_item
    ON user_item.item_id = item.id
JOIN tax
    ON tax.id = item.tax_id
WHERE user_item.user_id = ?
    AND item.deleted_at IS NULL
    AND user_item.deleted_at IS NULL
    AND tax.deleted_at IS NULL
```

This query works, however if I am given the items below:

```
+----+--------+--------------------+-------------+-------+---------------------+------------+------------+
| id | tax_id | name               | description | price | created_at          | updated_at | deleted_at |
+----+--------+--------------------+-------------+-------+---------------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |      2 | foo                |             |  1.13 | 2017-07-30 15:20:14 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  2 |   NULL | bar                |             |  0.67 | 2017-07-30 15:20:25 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  3 |   NULL | baz                |             |  1.15 | 2017-07-30 15:22:33 | NULL       | NULL       |
+----+--------+--------------------+-------------+-------+---------------------+------------+------------+
```

Then the query only returns the item with id 1. I want id 2 and 3 as well.

How can I modify my query to achieve this?

I understand the problem of the query is this part: `ON tax.id = item.tax_id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what `left join`s are for:

```
SELECT item.*
FROM item
JOIN user_item
    ON user_item.item_id = item.id
LEFT JOIN tax -- Here!
    ON tax.id = item.tax_id
WHERE user_item.user_id = ?
    AND item.deleted_at IS NULL
    AND user_item.deleted_at IS NULL
    AND tax.deleted_at IS NULL
```

Comment: I see.. I haven't used left join before. I tried modifying it, but received this error: `sql: Scan error on column index 1: converting driver.Value type <nil> ("<nil>") to a int: invalid syntax`. I think that is because I am trying to compare `NULL` to `INT`?

Comment: Yup - this probably comes from the code the **calls** this query and attempts convert one of the columns in the result to an `int` (when the actual returned value) is a `null`

Comment: Ah I see, yes you're right this is programming bug and I should be using `NullInt64` type where I am using `int`, according to some research I did. But the query itself is working properly. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: One more thing, do you think it would be a bad idea to set ID's to "0", or is that bad practices for a db? Or should I stick with `NULL` in this case?

Comment: @Lansana I wouldn't convert `null` to `0`. `0` is an actual value, while `null` has the meaning of "no value". If an item doesn't have any tax on it, `null` is the way to go (IMHO).

Comment: @Lansana Note that you can't use `0` for a foreign key if there is no such value in the referenced table.

Comment: Good points! Thanks. Gonna have to use the `NullInt64` and convert to `int` where needed in business logic.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is to put the `deleted_at` condition in the `on` clause.  If you want `NULL` values to match between the tables, then write this as:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM item i JOIN
     user_item ui
     ON ui.item_id = i.id LEFT JOIN
     tax t
     ON NOT (t.id <=> i.tax_id) AND  -- ids are the same or both `NULL`.
        t.deleted_at IS NULL
WHERE ui.user_id = ? AND
      i.deleted_at IS NULL AND
      ui.deleted_at IS NULL ;
```

Comment: When I run this query, I get 5 results back. 2 of each of the ones with `NULL` tax_id field, and one of the one with present tax_id field. But I like the idea of moving the deleted_at query, I am still working on better SQL syntax.

Comment: Thumbs up for the recommendation of deleted_at though. I was putting all deleted_at in my `WHERE` clause, but makes much more sense to put it on the respective joins.